# How to keep a JButton pressed after its JPanel loses focus

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have found how to keep a JButton in its pressed state using this code:

```
JButton[] buttons;
.
.
.
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
    {
        if(e.getSource() == buttons[i])
        {
            buttons[i].getModel().setPressed(true);
        }
        else
        {
            buttons[i].getModel().setPressed(false);
        }

    }
}
```

This code captures the clicked button, keeps it pressed, and makes all other buttons on the panel unpressed.  And this code works great... until the window loses focus (or more specifically, its parent JPanel loses focus).  After that, all the buttons return to a non-pressed state.

Right now the tutorial on how to write WindowFocusListeners is down.  Is there a way to make a JButton's pressed state persist through a loss of focus?

Comment: pick an answer bub. nearly at 4 years since you asked this

Answer (score 17):

Why not simply use a series of JToggleButtons and add them to the same ButtonGroup object? All the hard work is done for you since the toggle button is built to stay in pressed state if pressed. Think of it as a JRadioButton that looks like a JButton (since in actuality, JRadioButton *descends* from JToggleButton).

For example:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BunchOfButtons extends JPanel {
   private static final String[] TEXTS = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"};
   private ButtonGroup btnGroup = new ButtonGroup();
   private JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);

   public BunchOfButtons() {
      JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 5, 0));
      BtnListener btnListener = new BtnListener();
      for (String text : TEXTS) {
         JToggleButton toggleBtn = new JToggleButton(text);
         toggleBtn.addActionListener(btnListener);
         toggleBtn.setActionCommand(text);
         btnPanel.add(toggleBtn);
         btnGroup.add(toggleBtn);
      }

      JPanel otherPanel = new JPanel();
      otherPanel.add(textField ); // just to take focus elsewhere

      setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
      setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 15));
      add(btnPanel);
      add(otherPanel);
   }

   private class BtnListener implements ActionListener {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent aEvt) {
         textField.setText(aEvt.getActionCommand());
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      BunchOfButtons mainPanel = new BunchOfButtons();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("BunchOfButtons");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: You hit the nail on the head @Hovercraft Full Of Eels +1

Comment: `private class`??? I've never seen anything like that before. Could you elaborate (for me)?

Comment: It's a private inner class, that's all. It can only be used inside of the outer class, like an anonymous inner class, but unlike the anonymous variety, it can be used multiple times.

Comment: @fireshadow52: to clarify, an object derived from an anonymous inner class may be used multiple times, but you can only create one object with it while with a private inner class, you can call new MyPrivateInnerClass(...) as many times as needed.

Comment: where would I put the `private class soSo` imports? at the top with the outer class's imports? I guess that would make sense, but not sure

Comment: Valid alternative for some, but but doesn't answer the question. I can't change the framework to introduce button types and groups, in my case it's not an option.